# Regex For Matching First occurrence of a specific paragraph between two fix words

Tags: string, matching

I have a large Text in which I have to select text from "Call Charges" till first occurence of "Total" .
If I am saying "Call Charges" then it should not match "Conference Call Charges"
What should be the regex for that?

```
SMS Charges Usage   Free Usage  Charged Usage   Charges
Total   344 33  23
Call Charges    Usage   Free Usage  Charged Usage   Charges
Min:Sec Min:Sec Min:Sec Rs
Local   552:00  150:00  402:00  158.40
Local to CUG    42:00   0:00    42:00   0.00
STD 26:00   0:00    26:00   13.00
ISD 259:00  0:00    259:00  811.40
Total   879:00  150:00  729:00  982.80
Conference Call Charges Usage   Free Usage  Charged Usage   Charges
Min:Sec Min:Sec Min:Sec Rs
Total   345 344 
STD 9:00    0:00    9:00    4.50
ISD 8:00    0:00    8:00    11.20
Total   17:00   0:00    17:00   15.70
Total   344 33  23
SMS Charges Usage   Free Usage  Charged Usage   Charges
SMS SMS SMS Rs
SMS Local   2   2   0   0.00
Total   2   2   0   0.00
National Roaming Charges    Usage   Free Usage  Charged Usage   Charges
Min:Sec/SMS/MB  Min:Sec/SMS/MB  Min:Sec/SMS/MB  Rs
Incoming Calls  17:00   0:00    17:00   0.00
Total   0.00
```

Comment: Have you tried a regex which didn't worked for you? please share it. Even better if you'd share it via [regex101](https://regex101.com/) or similar

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you want match "Call Charges" at the start of the line, so you can use `^Call Charges` for the start and `^Total` for the end.
The trick is using `^` to match the start of line. Similarly you can use `$` to match end of line.

Comment: No, Its not matching as there are so many lines, It is matching the last "Total"

Comment: What do you mean it's not matching? You search for `^Call Charges` and it doesn't find anything? Which language/program are you using?

Answer (score 0):

You didn't specify the language you use, but if you turn on multiline mode (so `^` and `$` match the beginning and the end of the line) and dot capture all mode (so `.` captures new lines as well), you can easily do it with a simple beginning of a line match + a lookahead group:

```
^Call Charges.*?(?=^Total)
```

Comment: Alternatively, you can add `\n` to match a newline character: `^Call Charges(.*\n)*?(?=^Total)`